# Extract some part of string and then redirect using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to extract some part from url and then redirect user to the page using htaccess like below

Original:

- https://www.bosterbio.com/v/vspfiles/pdf/PA2036-1_DS.pdf

Extract the part after **pdf/** and before **_DS.pdf** and then redirect to the following:

Target:

- https://www.bosterbio.com/picokineDatasheet?sku=PA2036-1

Comment: There are already about 5638265826 answers to this question alone here on StackOverflow. None of those answers helped? Why not? And why should the 5638265827th answer suddenly do so? What should be different this time? Start by browsing through the "Related" section on the right side, you will get an idea about how that stuff works. And read the official documentation of apache's rewriting module. It comes with great examples.

Comment: Can you please answer, I am really struggling with this, the target URL must be dynamically created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^v/vspfiles/pdf/([^_]+)_DS\.pdf$ https://www.bosterbio.com/picokineDatasheet?sku=$1 [L,R]
```

you can also use RedirectMatch

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/v/vspfiles/pdf/([^_]+)_DS\.pdf$ https://www.bosterbio.com/picokineDatasheet?sku=$1
```

Comment: I need this "PA2036-1" in URL the whole sku including "-1"